# Why Go returns value 0 to an unassigned integer variable?

Tags: go

I was asked to declare a variable of integer type as:

```
var someInteger int8
```

Later when I printed this variable, it prints the value `0`.

My **Go Program** looks like:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  var someInteger int
  fmt.Println(someInteger)      // Prints 0 in terminal
}
```

My question is since I haven't assigned any value, so it should return some **Garbage value** like **C** instead of behaving like static variables, which automatically initialize by value **0**.

Comment: Please do not roll back valid edits. We don't need to know that you're new to Go (that's obvious from the question, anyway), and we don't need your P.S. These are just noise. They add no useful information.

Comment: You are also encouraged to read [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1). It explains these sorts of beginner questions very quickly. Takes about 15 minutes to read the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go makes this thing easy by adding sensible default values based on the type of the variables. For example:

```
var someInteger int8         // will print 0 as default
var someFloat float32        // will print 0 as default
var someString string        // will print nothing as it prints empty string
var someBoolean bool         // will print false as default
```

As @icza mentioned in his answer you can read more about it [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)

Answer (score 10):

In Go you can't access uninitialized variables / memory. If you don't initialize a variable explicitly, it will be initialized implicitly to the zero value of its type.

This is covered in [Spec: Variable declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

> If a list of expressions is given, the variables are initialized with the expressions following the rules for [assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments). Otherwise, each variable is initialized to its [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value).

Also mentioned at [Spec: Variables:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables)

> If a variable has not yet been assigned a value, its value is the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for its type.

And also covered in the [Go Tour: Zero Values](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12) which I highly recommend to take if you're learning the language.

> Variables declared without an explicit initial value are given their zero value.